# c# - problem with finding a point (2D)

Tags: c#, 2d, point

I am working with C# and I have 3 `System.Drawing.Point` variables (`A`, `B`, `C`) and the angle of `alpha`.

I need to find any point on the side 'a' and don't know how to manage this.

The angles alpha and beta have the same size!

[image]

Comment: Huh? The diagram is somewhat confusing, but without any additional constraints, finding *any* point on side 'a' is easy - I've picked point `B`.

Comment: Or, if you can describe the situation better, this question may be better suited to [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your text is right and your image wrong, by definition all points on `a` follow this equation:

```
P=t*B+(1-t)*C, 0<=t<=1
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are the extremities of your triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Algebra?

`y = m*x + c`

Basic line equation. Let's do it from A to B.

First, `m = (B.Y - A.Y)/(B.X - A.X)`.

Now substitute A. `A.Y = m * A.X + c`. Push stuff about algebraically to find `c`.

Now you can find any point between A and B by placing X or Y values into that equation and seeing what Y or X value is produced. Just be careful that you don't overstep the line boundaries.